# Django+Tastypie: Deleting only a couple of objects

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I'm using Django-Tastypie to provide a REST-API for my web application.

In this case I have a `PhotoGallery` object, which references to a couple of `Photos` using a intermediate table (using `through` on the ManyToMany field).

Unfortunately I have some trouble saving the `PhotoGallery` object through the REST interface, as it would require me to create the respective links in the intermediate table (which contain a bit of additional information like a sort index, etc.).

To simplify the API, I decided to expose the intermediate table as well, and now users can create and modify the relation between photos and the galleries.

To prevent the user of the REST-API having to delete each link with a single HTTP request, **I'm wondering if it is possible to use a single HTTP `DELETE` request to delete a selected number of objects**. Filtering does not seem to be respected with DELETE requests.

Comment: have you considered the `PATCH` method? Take a look the [Bulk Operations](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#bulk-operations) section in the docs. Pay attention to the `"deleted_objects": ` part.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was looking for (although I stumbled across that a few hours later). Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the `PATCH` method? Take a look the [Bulk Operations](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#bulk-operations) section in the docs. 
Pay attention to the `"deleted_objects": ...` part.